# How can I maximise the number of ribbon piece for a ribbon of given length n?

Tags: algorithm

I have a ribbon, its length is n. I want to cut the ribbon in a way that fulfils the following two conditions:

```
1. After the cutting each ribbon piece should have length a, b or c.
2. After the cutting the number of ribbon pieces should be maximum.
```

Find the number of maximum pieces after required cutting.

Input is of the form `n,a,b,c` where n is the original length of ribbon, and a,b,c are the required lengths of the ribbon.

```
For eg: I/P = 5 5 3 2
O/P = 2
```

Now, I am able to realize that this should follow a DP solution. A one dimensional DP where dp[n] represents the maximum number of ways for ribbon of length `n`.

Now, I am not sure if the recurrence relations will be of the form,

```
dp[n] = dp[n-a] + a;
dp[n] = dp[n-b] + b;
dp[n] = dp[n-c] + c;
```

Is this correct or there is some other way?

Edit: Implementation according to the first post:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int dp[100000];
int maxi (int a,int b,int c);
int main (void)
{
    int n,a,b,c;
    cin>>n>>a>>b>>c;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if ( i == 0 )
            dp[i] = 0;
        else
            dp[i] = maxi(dp[i-a],dp[i-b],dp[i-c])+1;
    }
    cout<<dp[n]<<"\n";
    return 0;
}

int maxi (int a,int b,int c)
{
    int ret;
    if ( a > b )
        ret = a;
    else 
        ret = b;
    if ( ret < c )
        ret = c;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not correct. How can dp[n] be assigned three different values ?

Comment: find min(a,b,c) and cut all the pieces of the same length?

Comment: Can't it be something like, `dp[n] = dp[n-a] + dp[n-b] + dp[n-c] + 3`? (I might definitely be wrong, but just asking).

Comment: @zubergu, I thought of that. But let's say, the ribbon length is `5` and `min = 2`, where `a=2, b=3, c=4` then after cutting, we will have pieces of length `2 2 1`. But `1` is not acceptable as a length. Therefore we cant do that.

Comment: you're getting closer, but that's not it. You can maybe think about the example you gave : dp[1] = 0, dp[2] = 1, dp[3] = 1, how would you compute dp[5] ?

Comment: ok, now I got the problem.

Comment: @vib, dp[5] = dp[2] + dp[3] = 2 = dp[n-b] + dp[n-c]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if n < 0:
    dp[n] = -infinity
if n == 0:
    dp[n] = 0
if n > 0:
    dp[n] = 1 + max(dp[n-a], dp[n-b], dp[n-c])
```

Comment: So, I implemented the above logic. But, when I submit this in the online judge, it gives a wrong answer for the input as `4000 1 2 3`. Is there something wrong in the implementation? I have added the implementation in the original post.

Comment: You don't appear to have any code corresponding to my first `dp[n] = -infinity` block. That's necessary in order to detect cases where the ribbon is impossible to cut up evenly.

Comment: I corrected the max function. But, @kevin, I didn't really add the case for dp[n] when n < 0 because in the for loop, the value of i will never be negative. So, if I add the condition for i < 0, it will never reach that. I know that i-a or i-b or i-c might come out to be negative, but then how do I write that condition?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know much about proper design of C code. If this was Python, you could just write a memoized recursive function, and you wouldn't even need a `dp` collection at all.

Comment: @Kevin, I just have one doubt. You have written, `if n < 0, dp[n] = -infinity`, here if `n < 0`, then how can you access an array with that index?

Comment: I guess you'd have to use a dictionary/hash/map, since regular arrays start at 0.

Comment: you may want to have a look at the code I provied to adress this issue. You never call dp[n] with n=0 directly but you do when you write dp[n-c], for n=1 for instance

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            dp[i] = 0;
        else {
            int A = (i-a>=0) ? dp[i-a] : -n-1;
            int B = (i-b>=0) ? dp[i-b] : -n-1;
            int C = (i-c>=0) ? dp[i-c] : -n-1;
            dp[i] = maxi(A,B,C)+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a small doubt, if I can take any negative value, right? In place of `-n-1`, right?

Comment: Not sure. It should be - infinity, and -n-1 is certainly enough. But I am not sure about taking only any negative value. Why don't you stick with -n-1 anyhow

Comment: Yup, that works but I asked if there is some special reason why you took that value.

Comment: You should upvote answers that helped you and validate the best one (in this case, Kevin's answer). For this questions ... and for other questions you asked previously.